# What can I do to make code be executed while the answer is one of a multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I tried to make that a code runs when x, determinated by a prompt is one of the four answers. With only one possibility it works well, but when I add more using && the program do nothing. (At the end of the program i put a break to execute the code only one time)

That's a short version of how the programm works...

```
var x = prompt("Ready?");
while(x == "yes"){
 window.alert("...Example...");

break;
}
```

And how I want to make it but doesn't works...

```
var x = prompt("Ready?")
while(x == "Yes" && x == "yes" && x == "yeS" && x == "YES")
 window.alert("...Example..."); 

break;
}
```

How can I do to make it works?

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with Java. Please try to figure out the name of the language you're trying to write code on, and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Try with `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x7uqad9L/1/

Comment: use || instead of &&. it will work.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry for my ignorance but given that I am doing it in a javascript playground and that I do it with the little I know of java, I thought it would be correct to label it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `||` instead of `&&`, and there's no need for a `while` statement, use `if` instead:

```
var x = prompt("Ready?")
if (x === "Yes" || x === "yes" || x == "yeS" || x == "YES") {
  window.alert("...Example..."); 
}
```

`||` means “or”, i.e. at least one of the conditions has to be true. If you use “and”, it means *all* of the conditions need to be true, which cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `.toLowerCase()` before the comparison so you don't have to deal with all different ways to capitalize a word.

```
var input = prompt("Ready?");
var x = input.toLowerCase();
while( x == "yes" )
 window.alert("...Example..."); 

break;
}
```

Then again, if you only need `yes` or `no` as options, I'd use a `window.confirm` instead of a `window.prompt`.

Edit: Hmm, if the question is that the answer HAS to be yes written in one of those 4 ways, I'd go for the array approach so you can add other options later on:

```
var allowed_answers = [ 'yes', 'Yes', 'yeS', 'YES' ];
if ( allowed_answers.includes( x ) ) {

}
```

Comment: I suppose this will work with English, since there is only one way, but in my language (Catalan) there is the correct way (sí) and the incorrect but "accepted" (si), therefore it would not be useful , no?
Thank you also

Comment: Then you have to go for a different approach indeed. Either the array method I decribe above. Or the || method described below. Or just normalize all the 'variant' letters, like I do with french: `"école".replace( "é", "e" );`

Comment: Stuff like this is why you don't often see prompt windows these days when the spelling of the answer matters. Most websites wil just offer a list of accepted answers to click so there can't be an issue with spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to do this

```js
do{
  var x = prompt("Ready?").toLowerCase();
  //toLowerCase() method convert (YES, Yes, yeS, etc) to (yes)
  if(x === "yes"){
    //If the condition is true, the loop breaks
    window.alert("...Example...");
    break;    
  }
}while(true)
```